# img doesn't show picture

Tags: javascript, php, image

I've made a IP camera, now I want to take a picture and show it on a website. I get the image and IP of camera, but it doesn't show.

It shows: `<img alt='' src='http://192.168.1.237/jpg/image.jpg?1432657009967'>` instead of image or picture

This is the javascript:

```
var urlSlika = newURL;
    $('#clickMe').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'template/test1.php',
            data: {
                'urlSlika': urlSlika,
                'ajax': true
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#data').text(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
    echo $_GET['urlSlika'];
} else {
?>
    <button type="button" id="clickMe">CLICK ME TO RUN PHP</button>
    <b id="data">
<?php } ?>
```

And another php file that shows picture:

```
<?php echo "<img alt='' src='" . $_GET["urlSlika"] . "'>";?>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.html(data)` instead of `.text(...)`?

Comment: 192.168 is an internal IP so it is only accessible to people within your network. It will not be accessible to a website unless this is also within the network

Comment: Although @JonStirling has already given the answer, I am confused: Either `$_GET["urlSlika"]` contains the url of the image (last line of your question) or it contains an image tag (second line of your question). Which is it?

Comment: it contains: <img alt='' src='http://192.168.1.237/jpg/image.jpg?1432657009967'> 
it's the url yes, url to picture

Comment: i used .html(data), not working